# Selenium API is Not working when I publish on IIS

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to scrape one website by API. If I run API Project and test then it's working fine but I publish on IIS it threw me an error like **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

If I'm using another website with the same API it's working fine.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my url");
              
var UserName = getElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@name,'txtEmail')]"));
if (UserName != null) UserName.Clear(); UserName.SendKeys(login);
Error = Error + "\nUser ctrl found";
            
var PSW = getElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@name,'txtPassword')]"));
if (PSW != null) PSW.Clear(); PSW.SendKeys(pwd);
Error = Error + "\nPSW ctrl found";

var Login = getElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]"));
if (Login != null) Login.Click();
Error = Error + "\nClick ctrl found";
```

can anyone help me with my query?

Comment: Can you post the piece of code where you are facing this issue?

Comment: from driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my url"); line I get an error

Comment: I am guessing the driver is the chromedriver like IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() from OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome namespace ? and if it is have you placed the chrome driver along with your app? You can hover on your driver while debugging and check if its the driver where you are facing this exception?

Comment: Yes, it is a Chrome driver. I face this error when I publish my code on iis

Comment: Please check if the chrome driver is a part of your source code and its set to copy always by right clicking it, my hunch is that the chrome driver is not deployed along with the source code to the IIS

Comment: It might cors issue as chrome driver is running in localhost

Comment: I also uploaded Chrome driver and chrome driver is working fine but when I navigate the URL then I think  it not open and it gives an error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace, and be sure to note which line of your code is throwing the exception.